# Spring Security bcrypt doesn't match

Tags: java, spring-security, bcrypt

I use the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

My password after hashed looks like that:

> $2a$04$oPljpAgVziMVABHS.z.znOhhu7oi8N5pxt0MS6IbOTWn.onfulrZe.

When I test, it writes on the console that the password doesn't look like BCrypt.

I tested it with http://regexr.com with the regex in `BCryptPasswordEncoder` class (`\A\$2a?\$\d\d\$[./0-9A-Za-z]{53}`) but it doesn't match.

I've try with a `A` in beginning and it's matched.
I've retry with my app and I've the same error.
Do you know what append?

**EDIT**

Encoders.java

```
public class Encoders {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@Import(Encoders.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-server-rest-api";
    private static final String SECURED_READ_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('read')";
    private static final String SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('write')";
    private static final String SECURED_PATTERN = "/api/**";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(SECURED_PATTERN).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SECURED_PATTERN).access(SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE)
                .anyRequest().access(SECURED_READ_SCOPE);
    }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

data.sql

```sql
INSERT INTO OAUTH_CLIENT_DETAILS(CLIENT_ID, RESOURCE_IDS, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPE, AUTHORIZED_GRANT_TYPES, AUTHORITIES, ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY)
 VALUES ('moha_security', 'resource-server-rest-api', 'A$2a$04$oPljpAgVziMVABHS.z.znOhhu7oi8N5pxt0MS6IbOTWn.onfulrZe',
 'read', 'password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit', 'USER', 10800, 2592000);
```

My request in postman

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 75a237ed-2e27-4af6-bca5-de558627f460' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F grant_type=password \
  -F username=201806ALE199501 \
  -F 'password=$2a$08$c.LqCdhrpAiF2Qn7yPGEw.6uL/phlSDW.QNXfMMWtnzSVX/paf2nK' \
  -F client_id=moha_security
```

My result in IntelliJ Console

```
2018-10-22 14:48:05.180  WARN 3483 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

Comment: Your SQL script is wrong, remove `A` from `A$2a$04$oPljpAgVziMVABHS.z.znOhhu7oi8N5pxt0MS6IbOTWn.onfulrZe`. Also your cURL command is wrong, replace `$2a$08$c.LqCdhrpAiF2Qn7yPGEw.6uL/phlSDW.QNXfMMWtnzSVX/paf2nK` with the plain text password.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally OK.

From wikipedia:
The prefix "$2a$" or "$2b$" (or "$2y$") in a hash string in a shadow password file indicates that hash string is a bcrypt hash in modular crypt format. The rest of the hash string includes the cost parameter, a 128-bit salt (Radix-64 encoded as 22 characters), and 184 bits of the resulting hash value.

About the A, it's just confusing,
Here is a small explanation:
[When should I use \A in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650549/when-should-i-use-a-in-a-regex)

Comment: Thank you for your precision. Do you any idea why BCryptPasswordEncoder doesn’t match my password ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing user roles definitions. Populate your roles in your database first.